# Node.js vs C++ Thrift performance

Tags: node.js, thrift, data-transfer

I have a node.js module that is run using a V8 addon that is compiled from code with Thrift client in C++. I have converted the module into complete node.js code and I am using 'thrift' and 'thriftpool' npm packages to manage thrift client connection pool. It is using TBinaryProtocol and TBufferedTransport make connectionsd with a thrift server.

Interestingly the performance of Node.js client is better than C++ client when sending a single integer, but no so true when sending very big json objects. C++ performance doesn't seem to be effected much but Node.js is degrading. Are there any improvements I can do here? Am I missing something?